# Why am I still getting an HTTPError despite excepting it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-catch, google-sheets-api, httpexception

I've imported and excepted the HTTPError in my code, yet my program halts when it appears. I'm not sure what I need to do. The error is because I'm using up my 100 second Google sheets read api quota, while I've applied for a higher limit, I have a unlimited daily limit and outside the 100 second limit, I can retry the same code and it will work. So, what I want my code to do is to retry after a simple time delay. However, my current code is halting with the exception. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
from urllib2 import HTTPError
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd
import gspread
import datetime
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import redis
import requests
import pygsheets
import json
import decimal
import time
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gc2 = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json')
ss2 = gc2.open_by_key('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

worksheets = ss2.worksheets()
Control = 'ON'
while(Control=='ON'):
    redishost='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXaws.com'
    r = redis.Redis(host=redishost, port=XXXX, db=0)
    for wkst in worksheets:
        if wkst.title == 'Log' or wkst.title == 'Control':
            pass
        else:
            url_done = True
            while(url_done):
                try:
                    print "worksheet: {}".format(wkst.title)
                    bid_val = wkst.get_value('O2')
                    if bid_val:
                        r.hmset("plcmnt:{}".format(wkst.get_value('I2')),{wkst.get_value('J2'):int(bid_val)})
                        wkst.update_cell('P2',datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                    wkst.update_cell('Q2',r.hget("plcmnt:{}".format(wkst.get_value('I2')),"{}".format(wkst.get_value('J2'))))
                    wkst.update_cell('R2',datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                    print "completed at {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                    url_done = False
                except HTTPError as err:
                    print err
                    print "failed updating sheet: '{}'".format(wkst.title)
                    print "retrying in 10 seconds"
                    time.sleep(10)
                    url_done = True
    Control = 'OFF' 
print "Control is {} at {}".format(Control,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Error:

```
  File "URL_Bid_Setter.py", line 39, in <module>
    wkst.update_cell('Q2',r.hget("plcmnt:{}".format(wkst.get_value('I2')),"{}".format(wkst.get_value('J2'))))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygsheets/worksheet.py", line 212, in get_value
    return self.get_values(addr, addr, include_empty=False)[0][0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygsheets/worksheet.py", line 242, in get_values
    value_render=value_render)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygsheets/client.py", line 323, in get_range
    result = self._execute_request(spreadsheet_id, request, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygsheets/client.py", line 418, in _execute_request
    response = request.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 844, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 429 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/values/6326%3Angoisao.vn%21I2%3AI2?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&alt=json&majorDimension=ROWS returned "Insufficient tokens for quota 'ReadGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXXXXXXX'.">
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: You are catching `urllib2.HTTPError`, not `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError`.

Comment: Yes that worked thank you. I just replaced the httplib call with `from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError` and changed case of HTTPError in the exception clause to `HttpError`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Google class

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError`

is unrelated to the exception

`urllib2.HTTPError`

(Just noticed the comments — so, this was indeed the solution, good!)